# I'm trying to improve Scintilla to recognize java by speech. Does anyone know if this is possible with Scintilla?

Tags: speech-recognition, speech, speech-to-text, scintilla, scite

I looked this up a lot but didn't find anything useful. Also is there any API support to do this? Any links and ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I wrote up a module to connect Scintilla to Text Services Framework; it was published in the [June 2007 issue of MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc187238.aspx).  This would let Scintilla support general dictation.  However, Java is not English, and dictating Java into an English recognizer usually ends up in tears.

Building a language-specific recognizer for Java would be a lot of work; in particular, you would most likely want some Intellsense-like feedback in the 'identifier' parts of a grammar to provide the most likely completions for a given phoneme stream.

Comment: I'm actually trying to do this with limited scope for now, as in only for the keywords and reserved literals of java. Since those words are English words, do you think if I will be successful in implementing speaker independent isolated word recognition on top of Scintilla? Do you have a better suggestion for an editor to implement this? Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: It depends on your definition of 'success'.  Can you hook up a recognizer (sapi in-process recognizer, for example) with a command-and-control gramar built around a set of keywords and get Scintilla to insert the text?  Yes, and it would be relatively straightforward.  Will it be something that people want to use?  Probably not.  People tend not to speak in isolated words, and that drives accuracy way down.  Once you've got the text in, most people want to correct it by voice; correction is a *much* harder item to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard any reports that speech recognition works with Scintilla. I seem to remember someone asking about it [here](http://dir.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.scintilla.devel), and the reply was that you Scintilla currently didn't support anything like that. I think you have to implement it yourself.

Try checking [here](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaRelated.html) for all projects related to Scintilla. You may find something helpful.

Comment: would I be able to implement it? Does Scintilla have its API with enough support?

Comment: I am not sure, I once heard of someone trying to create a speech-recognition SciTE plugin, however, he failed. I wish you good luck.